# Unable to run Project in Xcode 6.1. Issues related to usage of nonARC files in ARC project

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, xcode6.1, ios8.1

Im having trouble running an ARC enabled project in Xcode 6.1. Please note that this project consists of a few non-ARC compliant files also. For each of these files I have specified the compiler flag "-fno-objc-arc" in the project compile sources.

The exact same code works just right on Xcode 6. However, Xcode 6.1 is throwing out errors and warning related to non ARC code like dealloc and retain in spite of the compiler flags. Once i clear such offending code, the system throws the classic 'libxml/tree.h' file not found error.

I have tried cleaning the code, restarting the system and even re-installed Xcode itself, but all in vain.

Could someone please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks!